# Проверить, принадлежит ли какая-либо точка отрезка заданной (заданным) окружностям

Tags: c++, геометрия

Привет. Прошу помощи. В общем задача: на координатной плоскости задается отрезок с началом в точке А и с концом в точке В. Также задаются круги (можно и 1 круг) с центрами в точках M1,M2,M3,...M100 и с радиусами R1,R2,R3,...,R100. Нужно проверить, принадлежит ли какая-либо точка отрезка заданной (заданным) окружностям.

В общем-то это задача из олимпиады, код компилируется на сервере. Мой код: http://ideone.com/J5MJEH

```
double xA, yA, xB, yB;
int count = 0;
int n;

cin >> xA >> yA >> xB >> yB; // Координаты A и B отрезка: 
cin >> n; // Количество окружностей

double * * Arr = new double * [3]; // Задаем массив для кругов, в каждой строчке которого будут хранится x,y,r круга
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    Arr[i] = new double[3];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        cin >> Arr[i][j];
    }
}
double r12 = sqrt((xB - xA) * (xB - xA) + (yB - yA) * (yB - yA)); // Длина отрезка от A до B
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    double r1 = sqrt((Arr[i][0] - xA) * (Arr[i][0] - xA) + (Arr[i][1] - yA) * (Arr[i][1] - yA)); // Длина отрезка от т. M до A
    double r2 = sqrt((Arr[i][0] - xB) * (Arr[i][0] - xB) + (Arr[i][1] - yB) * (Arr[i][1] - yB)); // Длина отрезка от т. M до B

    if (((r12 * r12 + r1 * r1) - r2 * r2) >= 0 && ((r12 * r12 + r2 * r2) - r1 * r1) >= 0) { // Если перпендикуляр опущенный на прямую, проведенную через A u B лежит на отрезке AB, то проверяем, равен или больше ли радиус окружности
        double d = (abs((yB - yA) * Arr[i][0] + (xB - xA) * Arr[i][1] + (xA * yB - yA * xB))) / sqrt((yB - yA) * (yB - yA) + (xB - xA) * (xB - xA));
        if ((Arr[i][2] - d) >= 0) {
            count++;
        }
    } else { // Иначе, если перпендикуляр опущенный на прямую лежит вне отрезка, то проверяем, равен или больше ли радиус одному из отрезков от точки М до А или В
        if ((Arr[i][2] - r1) >= 0 || (Arr[i][2] - r2) >= 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
cout << count;
```

В комментариях кода написал, что,где, как нахожу.

То, как определить, падает ли перпендикуляр на отрезок, я взял отсюда: http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/misc/perp.php, а именно неравенства: B2 <= A2 + C2, C2 <= A2 + B2.

В общем-то программа работает, но, вероятно, не всегда правильно. Уже достаточно много перепробовал тестовых примером, всё правильно определяет. Но, когда отправляю решение на сервер олимпиады, сервер говорит: "Wrong Answer". Я все грешу на типы. Сможете помочь?

Comment: Изначально они были в <>, но все равно ругалось. Дело совсем не в этом, не в "не подключении библиотек". На компьютере все отлично компилируется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не проверяете случай, когда часть отрезка лежит в одной окружности, а часть - в другой. Например, A(10, 10), B(10, 20), M1(10, 10), R1(5), M2(10, 20), R2(5). тут половина отрезка лежит в первой окружности, а половина - во второй.

http://ideone.com/TdMCuz

Я бы предложил следующий алгоритм. Для каждой окружности проверяем, лежит ли отрезок в ней полностью (т. е. лежат ли оба конца отрезка внутри окружности). Если да, то ответ - "да", выходим. Если оба конца отрезка вне окружности, переходим к следующей окружности. Если один конец внутри, а другой - снаружи, то обезаем отрезок, оставляя только ту его часть, что снаружи, и продолжаем проверки. Если после проверки всех окружностей остался ненулевой участок отрезка, ответ - "нет".

Comment: Если оба конца отрезка находиться вне пределов окружности, то это абсолютно не значит, что часть отрезка не лежит внутри окружности.

Comment: KoVadim прав. и fori1ton прав. Сейчас покумекаю

Comment: @KoVadim, точно, не подумал об этом. Тогда проверка несколько усложняется, придётся делать её рекурсивно, так как окружность может разбить отрезок на два.

Comment: @fori1ton, спасибо! Благодаря Вашему примеру нашел ошибку - неправильно считался d, нужно было так:

    double d = (abs((yA-yB)*Arr[i][0] + (xB-xA)*Arr[i][1] + (xA*yB-yA*xB)))/sqrt((yB-yA)*(yB-yA) + (xB-xA)*(xB-xA));

Изначально неправильно вывел формулу для нахождения расстояния от точки до прямой.

Answer (score 3):

Проверку того, что *какая-либо* точка отрезка принадлежит окружности, можно заменить на проверку всего лишь трёх точек: концов отрезка и проекции центра окружности на прямую, содержащую отрезок (третью точку берём *только* если она принадлежит отрезку).

Вы же проверяете третью точку, но не проверяете края. То есть, теряете случай, когда очень короткий отрезок пересекает границу окружности. (Плюс наверное где-то ошибки реализации из-за очень «низкоуровневого» кода.)

Реализация не очень сложна (но придётся вспомнить геометрию за 9-ый класс):

```
bool GetProjection(const Segment& segment, const Point& source,
                   Point& projection)
{
    Vector direction = segment.end - segment.begin;
    double segmentLength = direction.Length();
    Vector unitDirection = direction / segmentLength;
    Vector beginToSource = source - segment.begin;
    double projectionLength = scalarProduct(unitDirection, beginToSource);
    if (projectionLength < 0 || projectionLength > segmentLength)
        return false;
    projection = segment.begin + unitDirection * projectionLength;
    return true;
}

bool IsPointInCircle(const Point& point, const Circle& circle)
{
    var radiusVector = point - circle.center;
    return radiusVector.Length() <= circle.radius;
}

bool AnyPointInCircle(const Segment& segment, const Circle& circle)
{
    Point projection;
    return
        IsPointInCircle(segment.begin, circle) ||
        IsPointInCircle(segment.end, circle) ||
        (GetProjection(segment, circle.center, projection) &&
            IsPointInCircle(projection, circle));
}
```

Классы `Point`, `Vector` и прочие определяются самоочевидным образом.

Comment: А как насчёт случая 2?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Вы какой случай имеете в виду?

Comment: Когда прямая пересекает окружность, а отрезок не пересекает. В моём ответе есть рисунок.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Этот случай покрыт. В первом абзаце ответа: «третью точку берём _только_ если она принадлежит отрезку». В коде для вашего второго случая функция `GetProjection` возвращает `false`.

Comment: Значит, логика поиска наименьшего значения функции (расстояния до центра окружности) на отрезке сработала в очередной раз. Dito.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Минимум выпуклой функции на выпуклом компакте, классика, по идее.

Comment: А можно просто связать с отрезком ось абсцисс и построить функцию.

Comment: теперь пытаюсь оценить, какое решение проще.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Попробуйте реализовать оба. Так проще всего. У меня код почти готов. (По модулю несложной реализации геометрических примитивов.)

Comment: Прога готова. Кажется, она попроще.

Answer (score 0):

На рисунке изображены два случая непересечения отрезком окружности:

1. Когда прямая не пересекает окружность.
2. Когда прямая пересекает окружность, а отрезок не пересекает.

[image: Circle2]

Для каждой окружности **(R,M)** и отрезка **AB** можно применить следующий алгоритм:

1. Вычисляем коэффициенты уравнения
   **(A+qB)/(1+q) on (R,M)**, или
   **(xa + q* xb - (1+q)* xm)<sup>2</sup> + (ya + q* yb - (1+q)* ym)<sup>2</sup> = (1+q)<sup>2</sup>*R<sup>2</sup>**:
   С<sub>2</sub>q<sup>2</sup>+2C<sub>1</sub>q+C<sub>0</sub> = 0, где
   C<sub>0</sub> = (xa - xm)<sup>2</sup> + (ya - ym)<sup>2</sup> - R<sup>2</sup>,
   C<sub>1</sub> = (xa - xm) * (xb - xm) + (ya - ym) * (yb - ym) - R<sup>2</sup>,
   C<sub>2</sub> = (xb - xm)<sup>2</sup> + (yb - ym)<sup>2</sup> - R<sup>2</sup>.
2. Если C<sub>0</sub> <= 0, точка A попала в круг.
3. Если C<sub>2</sub> <= 0, точка B попала в круг.
4. Если det = C<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> - C<sub>0</sub>C<sub>2</sub> <= 0, прямая АB с кругом не пересекается.
5. Вычисляем корни уравнения q<sub>1</sub> и q<sub>2</sub> (если есть).
6. Если **q<sub>1</sub> >= 0 ИЛИ q<sub>2</sub> >= 0**, то попали.
   Иначе не попали.

Программа:

```
function are_crossed($a, $b, $r, $m){
    $rr = $r*$r;        
    $am = array($a[0] - $m[0], $a[1] - $m[1]);      // вектор AM 
    $bm = array($b[0] - $m[0], $b[1] - $m[1]);      // вектор BM 
    $eq = array(
        $am[0]*$am[0] + $am[1]*$am[1] - $rr,
        $am[0]*$bm[0] + $am[1]*$bm[1] - $rr,
        $bm[0]*$bm[0] + $bm[1]*$bm[1] - $rr
    );
    $det = $eq[1]*$eq[1] - $eq[0]*$eq[2];

    if($eq[0] <= 0) return 1;                       // начало отрезка попало в круг
    if($eq[2] <= 0) return 2;                       // конец отрезка попал в круг
    if($det < 0) return -1;                         // линия не пересекает круг

    $d = sqrt($det); 
    $root1 = ( -$eq[1] - $d) / $eq[2];              // первая точка пересечения линии и круга 
    $root2 = (-$eq[1]+$d)/$eq[2];                   // вторая точка пересечения линии и круга

    if(($root1>=0) return 3;                        // первая точка принадлежит отрезку
    if(($root2>=0) return 4;                        // вторая точка принадлежит отрезку
    return -2;                                      // обе точки пересечения - вне отрезка 
} 

$a = array(5, 20);
$b = array(25, 5);
$m = array(5, 5);
$r = 12;

$result = are_crossed($a, $b, $r, $m);
print "A = "; print_r($a);
print "<br>B = "; print_r($b);
print "<br>M = "; print_r($m);
print "<br>R = $r";
print("<br>result = $result<br>");
print($result>0 ? "пересекаются" : "не пересекаются");
```

Результаты:

```
A = Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 20 ) 
B = Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 5 ) 
M = Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 5 ) 
R = 12
result = 3
пересекаются
```

Comment: Что-то уж больно легко для олимпиады.

Comment: @BuilderC Олимпиада - это не трудно. Это сложно. Задачу выбирали те, у кого есть статистика пробелов в знаниях (cвойства отрезка вспоминаются не сразу).

Comment: Что здесь в формулах **q**?

Comment: @sercxjo Это отношение, в котором точка внутренняя точка отрезка делит этот отрезок, И оно от нуля до бесконечности, кстати. Так что спасибо за вопрос.